# Adding to the schema of a subscribing database

Tags: sql-server, replication, transactional-replication

Transactional Replication on SQL Server 2005 Enterprise x64 (SP3).

I need to add check constraints to a databases that is the target for a replication, but I cannot add the check constraints to the publishing database. The Problem is that the replication process keeps removing my constraints. How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create some ddl triggers to prevent the constraint being removed. however replication would fail horribly if you alowed the publishing database to publish data that violated the constraint, which is a distinct posibility if you cannot add the constraint to the master database.

Comment: Fortunately, the constraints are built from the replication triggers so violation is near impossible.